# Unexpected Error in IEEEtrans.cls

Tags: errors, ieeetran

I am new to LaTeX.
I have been working on a .tex file and very unexpectedly, encountered the following error:

```
 Error message - **There is a '}' missing: unexpected end of line.**
```

in the following line of my IEEEtrans.cls files.

```
 {\catcode`\|=0 \catcode`\\=12
 |xdef|@IEEEbackslash{\}}
```

Any pointers or remedies?

Comment: I don't think that is a TeX error, is it an error message from your editor, which may not be able to understand the syntax used there. But you should almost never need to load the class file into your editor.

Comment: also does it really say `|xdef|@IEEEbackslash{}}` I'd have expected `|xdef|@IEEEbackslash{\}`

Comment: If they had used `{\escapechar=\m@ne\xdef\@IEEEbackslash{\string\\}}` the editor wouldn't complain. Alternatively, `\edef\@IEEEbackslash{\expandafter\@gobble\string\\}`. Or, even better, `\let\@IEEEbackslash\@backslashchar`